# Can OAuth2 and session based authentication coexist in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a web application which uses spring security for session based logins using username and password authentication with the following security application context xml.

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/files/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config='true' entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" method="OPTIONS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="REGISTERED" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login_security_check" authentication-failure-handler-ref="xxxAuthenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="xxxAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/data/logout" success-handler-ref="xxxLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <remember-me key="xxxRem" />
</http>
<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="roleVoter" />
            <beans:ref bean="authenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.xxx.web.security.XXXUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService'>
        <password-encoder hash="md5">
            <salt-source user-property="username" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/login" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="defaultEntryPoint" ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
</beans:bean>
```

Now I want to expose my web services for a mobile app, so I am looking to implement OAuth2. I've read the examples provided on github.

I was wondering how these two security flows can co-exist as the intercept url pattern will be same for both the flows?

Comment: Have u got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the `access=""` rules for the resources that are shared between the UI and the OAuth resources. It's not very common for those two to really cross over very much, but I guess for simple apps it might be possible through content negotiation. It's probably easiest to use the SpEL support in XML (or switch to Java config). Example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/** access="isFullyAuthenticated() or #oauth2.hasScope('read')"/>
```

For an alternative approach you could create aliases for your endpoints and protect them with separate filter chains, one for the token and one for cookie-based authentication. Example:

```
@RequestMapping({ "/user", "/api/user" })
public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("name", principal.getName());
    return map;
}
```

where "/user" is protected as a normal resource (i.e. with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in Java config), and "/api/user" is separately configured (i.e. with a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` in Java config).

Comment: I tried to configure both Spring Security for session login and Spring Security OAuth2 for token login. However, OAuth2 always override the session check even I have already session login, it still shows error: unauthorized because it does not find then token

Comment: The sparklr sample in spring-security-oauth2 does it I think (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java#L66). I'll also update the answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: @Dave - I'm also facing the same issue where UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter always overrides OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617218/how-oauth-token-based-and-session-based-authorization-works-together-in-spring